# Measure of Separation for fuzzy clustering

Tags: python, scikit-learn, fuzzy-classification

Is there a measure of separation such as the Sillohete score for fuzzy clustering? I understand the logic for Hard-clustering algorithms but not sure about fuzzy. Is there a Python package for that such as scikit-learn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using classing distance measurement such as K-Means?

Otherwise, this page has code about fuzzy c-means including a distance calculation:
https://pythonhosted.org/scikit-fuzzy/_modules/skfuzzy/cluster/_cmeans.html

There is also a publication but no code:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/256471114_Fuzzy_Distance_Measure_and_Fuzzy_Clustering_Algorithm

Comment: If you consider the answer somewhat usefull, don't hesitate to upvote it as acknowledgment :)